# Am I HSA qualified if I am covered on two health plans, one of which is not high deductible?

Tags: united-states, irs, health-insurance, hsa

I am trying to figure out whether I am legally permitted to open an HSA account. Here is the background: I am the primary account holder on a high deductible health care plan which comes with an HSA account that I can opt into. I am the secondary member on a plan that is not high deductible. Am I allowed to keep the HSA that comes with my plan, or am I obligated to decline it?

Comment: Is there a reason to be double insured? Would it make sense to drop one of them?

Comment: What is the point of paying for two health insurance plans? Seems like a waste of money

Comment: @Kat It's not a waste of money, but I'm not going to explain my personal situation here. You can see this link for examples of situations where a person may have dual coverage: https://www.ehealthinsurance.com/resources/individual-and-family/can-you-have-two-health-insurance-plans

Comment: @TTT Yes, and no. See my previous comment, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably not eligible for an HSA based on your secondary coverage.

From [IRS Pub 969](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p969.pdf) (emphasis added):

> #### Qualifying for an HSA
>
> To be an eligible individual and
> qualify for an HSA, you must meet the following requirements:
>
> - You are covered under a high deductible health plan (HDHP),    described later, on the first day of the month.
> - You have no other health coverage except what is permitted under Other health coverage, later.
> - You aren’t enrolled in Medicare.
> - You can’t be claimed as a dependent on someone else’s 2019 tax return.
>
> If you meet these requirements, you are an eligible individual even if
> your spouse has non-HDHP family coverage, ***provided your spouse’s
> coverage doesn’t cover you***.

Pub 969 also lists some specific exemptions to this rule about what kinds of "secondary coverage" you can have, but being covered by someone else's health insurance seems to be a pretty straightforward violation of the eligibility rules.